# frequent 401 errors on API requests through HAproxy

Tags: rest, api, haproxy, restful-authentication

We are seeing multiple 401 Authorization errors from clients sending GET requests to a rest API. Typically the next response will return a 200 OK. We tried testing this but from within our network we were unable to replicate this. The rest API is run on a tomcat server and we have looked through catalina logs but cannot determine if the client is actually submitting credentials.

Is there a way to determine if the client is making the request with credentials or not. The obvious way to also test was doing this outside our network and with credentials, no error but logically yes without. The client insists they are using credentials. We do have the use of HAProxy which reroutes all incoming requests to the appropriate ip but not sure if this can cause issues.

Do you think caching of credentials may be the issue?

Comment: How are the "credentials" submitted with the request? The `Authorization:` header? Query string parameters? Something else?  Have you tried the relatively simple step of capturing the request traffic with a packet sniffer, either on the app server or the proxy?

Comment: Didnt think of the packet sniffer. We are not sure how the client is doing it but since they are coding this, I would assume that the add the header with webrequest. I tried duplicating the scenario, and not including the header but   rather just including it in the url would cause a 401. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: installed wireshark and tshark. Not too familiar with these but trying to learn it. Is anyone familiar with tshark and if so, is it possible to read these packets? How would I read incoming API requests?